# Dynamically building Entity Framework Linq to SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to build a dynamic query in linq to SQL. In short, the problem I am trying to solve is as follows:

We have an existing SQL Server database with a number of tables that we want to be able to search in generically. This is a legacy database, so we are using Entity framework data-first (not code first).
In our database, we also have a metadata table that holds the table and column names of the other tables, and which columns are searchable.

For example, we might have a table named 'Vehicles' with a PK column called 'Vehicle_Id', and searchable columns named 'Type' and 'Colour'. Our metadata table would contain entries for the columns 'Type' and 'Colour' marking them as searchable.

The EF model and mapping for the Vehicle entity would look something like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMap()
    {
        This.ToTable("VEHICLES");
        This.HasKey(k => k.Id);
        This.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("VEHICLE_ID");
        This.Property(p => p.Type).HasColumnName("TYPE");
        This.Property(p => p.Colour).HasColumnName("COLOUR");
    }
}
```

A user then defines the search requirements (for instance, 'Type' of 'Car' or 'Colour' of 'Red' or 'Blue'). These search requirements are based on the column names.

I would like to be able to dynamically build the query, based on the field names defined in our metadata table, something like this:

```
var query = from v in context.Vehicles select v.Id;
foreach (var criterion in criteria)
{
    var fieldName = criterion.Field;  // Database field name, e.g. "TYPE"
    var value = criterion.Value;      // Search value, e.g. "CAR"

    var filter = [Filter based on field/value]

    results = query.Where(filter).ToList();
    // do something with results...
}
```

At the moment, I think I am about half-way there with the following extension method which is getting the entity mapping for a given table from the EF context. What I'm getting lost with is then finding the field based on field name (e.g. 'COLOUR') and building the filter based on this.

```
public static EntityType GetTableMapping(this DbContext context, string tableName)
{
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var storageMetadata = ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).GetMetadataWorkspace().GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace);
    var entityProps = storageMetadata.Where(s => s.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).Select(s => s as EntityType);
    return (from m in entityProps where string.Compare(m.Name, tableName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 select m).SingleOrDefault();
}
```